# Can we do transaction to firebase database if object doesn't exist?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase transaction below where it will increment `all` and `year` fields inside the `stat` object. But what if `stat` doesn't even exist, will firebase automatically create this object for me?

From what I've tested, I got an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of null` which obviously says `stat` is null. If so, how can I use transaction to create the object if it doesn't exist before?

```
const merchantRef = admin.database().ref("statistics/" + merchantId);
merchantRef.transaction(stat => {
  stat.all = (parseInt(stat.all) || 0) + price;
  stat.year = (parseInt(stat.year) || 0) + price;
  return stat;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether there is data at the location with by checking if `stat` is `null`.

```
const merchantRef = admin.database().ref("statistics/" + merchantId);
merchantRef.transaction(stat => {
  if (!stat) stat = { all: 0, year: 0 };
  stat.all += price;
  stat.year += price;
  return stat;
});
```

Comment: Thank Frank. I tried again but it still complains null stat. I think it's the left one in the assign statement.

Comment: Ah got it. I missed that. Updated to a simpler construct that fixed the problem.

Comment: wow, I didn't expect the fix would be this simple. It worked this time. Thanks Frank for prompt help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a transaction on a location that doesn't exist.  Even if it does exist, you should expect that the first call to your handler function will give you a null, and you will need to return what the data *should* be at that location.

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions):

> Because your update function is called multiple times, it must be able
>   to handle null data. Even if there is existing data in your remote
>   database, it may not be locally cached when the transaction function
>   is run, resulting in null for the initial value.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I checked the document, but what if the ```post``` in the doc sample is null, can the new post be created?

Comment: Yes, that was the meaning of the first sentence in my answer.  In any case, you need to figure out what *should* be at the location of the transaction.

Comment: Yes I understand. But in the example you just sent, if the post is null, it's a no-op, maybe we can enhance the document a bit to describe if post if null, how can we initialize it. Thanks again!

Comment: It's only a no-op if you code it to be that way.  You can return whatever you want the data to be at the location of the transaction, given either null (no data) or the existing data.